# How to select primary Sim in Dual sim supported cell to send an sms?

Tags: android, sms, sendmessage, dual-sim

How to select primary Sim in Dual sim supported cell to send an sms?

I have written a code which send an sms through 1st Sim even anyone of both are selected.

And even sms received from second sim

```
    private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{
    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Popup.this, 0,
        new Intent(SENT), 0);

    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Popup.this, 0,
        new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

    //---when the SMS has been sent---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

    //---when the SMS has been delivered---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
}
```

I want send to sms on selected sim.
But I could not found the solution.

Comment: The Android SDK does not have much support for multi-SIM devices. You will probably need to take this up with your device manufacturer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make Object of TelePhonyInfo.java which is telephonyInfo like this.
`TelephonyInfo telephonyInfo=TelephonyInfo.getInstance(getApplicationContext());`

Then check sim settings using following function:

```
public int  getDefaultSimmm(Context context) {

    Object tm = context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    Method method_getDefaultSim;
    int defaultSimm = -1;
    try {
        method_getDefaultSim = tm.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getDefaultSim");
        method_getDefaultSim.setAccessible(true);
        defaultSimm = (Integer) method_getDefaultSim.invoke(tm);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Method method_getSmsDefaultSim;
    int smsDefaultSim = -1;
    try {
        method_getSmsDefaultSim = tm.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getSmsDefaultSim");
        smsDefaultSim = (Integer) method_getSmsDefaultSim.invoke(tm);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return smsDefaultSim;
    }
```

based on defaultSim integer variable if 0 or 1. Send sms from SIM of your choice using this function:

```
public boolean sendSMS(Context ctx, int simID, String toNum, String centerNum, String smsText, PendingIntent sentIntent, PendingIntent deliveryIntent) {
        String name;

        try {
            if (simID == 0) {
                name = "isms";
                // for model : "Philips T939" name = "isms0"
            } else if (simID == 1) {
                name = "isms2";
            } else {
                throw new Exception("can not get service which for sim '" + simID + "', only 0,1 accepted as values");
            }
            Method method = Class.forName("android.os.ServiceManager").getDeclaredMethod("getService", String.class);
            method.setAccessible(true);
            Object param = method.invoke(null, name);

            method = Class.forName("com.android.internal.telephony.ISms$Stub").getDeclaredMethod("asInterface", IBinder.class);
            method.setAccessible(true);
            Object stubObj = method.invoke(null, param);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 18) {
                method = stubObj.getClass().getMethod("sendText", String.class, String.class, String.class, PendingIntent.class, PendingIntent.class);
                method.invoke(stubObj, toNum, centerNum, smsText, sentIntent, deliveryIntent);
            } else {
                method = stubObj.getClass().getMethod("sendText", String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, PendingIntent.class, PendingIntent.class);
                method.invoke(stubObj, ctx.getPackageName(), toNum, centerNum, smsText, sentIntent, deliveryIntent);
            }

            return true;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("apipas", "ClassNotFoundException:" + e.getMessage());
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            Log.e("apipas", "NoSuchMethodException:" + e.getMessage());
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            Log.e("apipas", "InvocationTargetException:" + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.e("apipas", "IllegalAccessException:" + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("apipas", "Exception:" + e.getMessage());
        }
        return false;
    }
```